# Heroku application Error Node.js please if anyone resolve what they are saying?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku Application error I don't understand why this will be happen.Can anyone tell me why this will be happening...? Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.

[here it is log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N497P.png)

[Here it is Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XIxl.png)

Comment: Post error log or any error details, your question is not enough to help you.

Comment: Could you share some application logs?

Comment: @kgangadhar i add the log picture

Comment: YOu should put here the package.json file i suspect your problem may be related to the start or build scripts

Comment: @jogarcia i added the package.json please review

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express i advise using also the express generator by using the command:

`npm install -g express-generator`

and then generate your app using the command:

`express`

In such a case your start and dev scripts should look like this

```
"scripts":{
  "dev": "nodemon",
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

Also your nodemon dependency should be added to your dev dependencies or not be added at all if you have it installed globally